# BitDefender Сканирование

Tags: php, debian, linux

Всем привет!
Есть фотохостинг. При каждой загрузке изображения выполняется его сканирование (через php). Проблема в том, что при каждом сканировании загружаются вирусные базы, а это около 10сек, после чего изображение сканируется и процесс закрывается. Хотелось бы как то это время уменьшить т.к. таких проверок будет очень много.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто исключить из сканирования файлы с изображениями.